A question on Theorem 3.4.6 of Vershynin - invariace of spherical distribution
The following is an excerpt from the proof that random vectors that are uniformly distributed on the sphere are sub-gaussian from Vershynin's "High Dimensional Probability".

$\textbf{Theorem 3.4.6}$ $\text{(Uniform distribution on the sphere is sub-gaussian)}$.
Let $X$ be a random vector uniformly distributed on the Euclidean sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with center at the origin and radius $\sqrt{n}$:
$$ X \sim \text{Unif}\left(\sqrt{n} \, S^{n-1}\right).$$
Then $X$ is sub-gaussian, and
$$ \|X\|_{\psi_2} \leq C. $$

Proof. Consider a standard normal random vector $g \sim N(0, I_n)$. As we noted in Exercise $\color{blue}{3.3.7}$, the direction $g/\|g\|_2$ is uniformly distributed on the unit sphere $S^{n-1}$. Thus, by rescaling we can represent a random vector $X \sim \text{Unif}\left(\sqrt{n} \, S^{n-1}\right)$ as
$$ X = \sqrt{n} \frac{g}{\|g\|_2}.$$
We need to show that all one-dimensional marginals $\langle X, x \rangle$ are sub-gaussian.

By rotation invariance, we may assume that $x = (1,0,\ldots,0)$, in which case $\langle X, x \rangle = X_1$, the first coordinate of $X$. We want to bound the tail probability
$$
p(t) := \mathbb{P} \left\{ |X_1| \geq t \right\} = \mathbb{P} \left\{ \frac{|g_1|}{\|g\|_2} \geq \frac{t}{\sqrt{n}} \right\}.
$$

My question is, what does rotation invariance refer to here, the Gaussian random variable or the spherical random variable? How I would interpret that is if $g$ is gaussian then $Ug$ is also gaussian, for $U$ an orthogonal matrix. But it seems to me that the matrix that extracts only the first element of a vector cannot be orthogonal, as it is singular. What does Vershynin mean here precisely? Thank you.

Do you observe that when $X$ is Uniform on the sphere, the projections $\langle X, x \rangle$ have the same distribution for all unit vectors $x$?

@Mathaddict No, this needs justification.

$\langle X, Ux \rangle = \langle U*X, x \rangle \sim  \langle X, x \rangle $ because of rotational invariance of $U$.

@Mathaddict What is even $U$ in your notation? It's unclear what you mean.

As a remark, the proof of this is somewhat complicated. Just note that $X$ is bounded, so it is sub-gaussian.

Given $x\in S^{N-1}$, one can always find an orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that $Qx = e_1$. One way to see this is to take $Q^T$ which sends $e_1$ to $x$, and then use the Gram-Schmidt procedure to find $x_2,\dots,x_n$ with $x,x_2,\dots,x_N$ forming an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb R^N$. Recall as well that $Q$ preserves inner products, that is, $\langle Qx, Qy \rangle = \langle x,y \rangle$. Finally, note $Q(S^{N-1}) = S^{N-1}$. The preceding shows $Q(S^{N-1}) \subset S^{N-1}$. As for surjectivity, given $\omega \in S^{N-1}$, $Q(Q^T\omega) = \omega$.
Next, the surface measure $\sigma$ on $S^{N-1}$ is rotationally invariant, that is, $Q_\sharp \sigma = \sigma$ where $Q_\sharp \sigma = \sigma \circ Q^{-1}$.
Combining the aforementioned, we get
$$\int_{S^{N-1}}\langle \omega,x\rangle \,\sigma(d\omega) = \int_{S^{N-1}}\langle Q\omega,Qx\rangle \,\sigma(d\omega) = \int_{S^{N-1}}\langle Q\omega,e_1\rangle\,\sigma(d\omega) = \int_{Q(S^{N-1})}\langle \omega,e_1\rangle\,(Q_\sharp\sigma)(d\omega) = \int_{S^{N-1}}\langle w,e_1\rangle\sigma(d\omega)\,.$$

Thank you +1. The only thing that you take for granted is $Q(S^{N-1}) = S^{N-1}$ but is that even true given that $Qx = e_1$?

edited @JohnK .
